# Ionic 2 - ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'FILE_URI' of undefined

Tags: camera, ionic2

Im trying to retrive images from my gallery using Ionic 2 and ionic-native plugin.but it give me this error when i set my `sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`

can some one help me here

error log

```
app.bundle.js:2265 Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'PHOTOLIBRARY' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'PHOTOLIBRARY' of undefined
    at AdminPage.getImage (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:63654:65)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_AdminPage_0.handleEventInternal (viewFactory_AdminPage:482:33)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.handleEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:14022:30)
    at AppView.triggerEventHandlers (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:18329:37)
    at eval (viewFactory_AdminPage:885:106)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:33471:37
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:32848:87
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:2258:25)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:17573:43)
    at NgZone.run (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:17521:41)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]Zone.run @ app.bundle.js:2265zoneBoundFn @ app.bundle.js:2235
```

code -

```
getImage(){
    var options = {
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    };
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64:
      let base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
    });

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at the ionic-native camera.ts code - [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/plugins/camera.ts).

The sourceType is defined as shown below:

sourceType?: number;

The numbers for the different PictureSourceType are given as below:

PHOTOLIBRARY : 0,
CAMERA : 1,
SAVEDPHOTOALBUM : 2

So why don't you try with sourceType: 0

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and solved it.
the problem:

```
public camera: Camera;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}
```

the solution:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public camera: Camera) {}
```